# jQuery Submit Form Populate Input Value Attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I'm wanting to get the current page URL on submit from my form and populate the "value" attribute on an input type hidden with the URL on submission.

Currently I'm statically adding in a URL (http://www.google.com) to see if I'm populating the value attribute the right way but using `.val()` on the selector however, this doesn't seem to populate the attribute?

See my submit function below - I have added a class to the input called `referrer-page`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" class="referrer-page" name="00N20000002A4au" type="text" value="URL HERE!" />
```

**jQuery**

```
setupOnSubmit = function () {
    var submitButton = $j('.submit_form'),
        emailIcon = $j('.email-icon'),
        referrerPage = $j('.referrer-page');

    emailIcon.on('click', function(){
        $j(this).submit();
        referrerPage.val("http://www.google.com");
    });

    //Pass URL on submit 
    submitButton.on('click', function(){
        referrerPage.val("http://www.google.com");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it is not clear what all those functions do. Try something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(':hidden[name="00N20000002A4au"]').val(window.location);
    return true;
});
```

Code above is not tested, just an idea.

Also see `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: This worked - I just used the variable referrerPage.val(window.location); Works a treat! Thanks!!